# Retrieve secrets from Vault using csi driver returning “permission denied”

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, hashicorp-vault

I can get a token using curl:

```
curl \
--request POST \
--data '{"jwt": "'$TOKEN_REVIEW_SJWT'", "role": "teste-role"}'\
http://<ip>:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
```

I’m able to `vault login <token>` and read the secret `vault read secret/data/k8s-secret`. But when I deploy a pod to test it, is returning “permission denied”.

```
Warning  FailedMount  103s (x23 over 32m)   kubelet, <ip>  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store-inline" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod csi/nginx-secrets-store-inline, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error making mount request: couldn't read secret "k8s-secret": Error making API request.

URL: GET http://<vault-ip>:8200/v1/%!!(MISSING)E(MISSING)2%!C(MISSING)secret/data/k8s-secret%!!(MISSING)E(MISSING)2%!D(MISSING)
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
  * permission denied
```

Pods status:

```
kubectl get pods -n csi
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
csi-secrets-store-csi-driver-4n789   3/3     Running   0          24h
csi-secrets-store-csi-driver-8zfbp   3/3     Running   0          10d
csi-secrets-store-csi-driver-b6hqv   3/3     Running   0          10d
vault-csi-provider-f488v             1/1     Running   0          11d
vault-csi-provider-l2982             1/1     Running   0          24h
vault-csi-provider-zztxb             1/1     Running   0          10d
```

To install the vault provider and csi driver:

```
helm install vault hashicorp/vault -n csi\
  --set "server.enabled=false" \
  --set "injector.enabled=false" \
  --set "csi.enabled=true"
```

```
helm install csi secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver -n csi
```

Pod yaml to consume the secret:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: nginx-secrets-store-inline
 namespace: app
spec:
 containers:
 - image: nginx
   name: nginx
   volumeMounts:
   - name: secrets-store-inline
     mountPath: “/mnt/secrets-store”
     readOnly: true
 serviceAccountName: app-sa
 volumes:
   - name: secrets-store-inline
     csi:
       driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
       readOnly: true
       volumeAttributes:
         secretProviderClass: vault-secret
```

Comment: It reads like the secret csi driver doesn't have sufficient permission to mount your secret "k8s-secret" to the pod. Are you certain that the necessary RBAC for the driver has been installed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @gohm'c. I installed the driver using helm.
I have this cluster role created https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/secrets-store-csi-driver/blob/master/charts/secrets-store-csi-driver/templates/role.yaml and it's associated with the service account secrets-store-csi-driver.

Comment: And your external secret provider is AWS (assumed by looking to your tag), can you post the status of the driver pods, helm parameters you set during the installation, and the yaml that deployed the app which consume the secret?

Comment: I edited the question with the answers @gohm'c. The cluster is in EKS and the vault cluster is hosted on EC2.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the pod when I removed the double quotes from the SecretProviderClass.

```
objects: |
   - objectName: password
     secretPath: secret/data/k8s-secret/
     secretKey: password
```